# Serverless invoke error: "is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:BatchWriteItem on resource: arn:aws:..."

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, amazon-dynamodb

I have this **iamRoleStatements** on my **serverless.yml**, which should allow those actions to my lambda functions:

```
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - dynamodb:Query
    - dynamodb:Scan
    - dynamodb:GetItem
    - dynamodb:PutItem
    - dynamodb:UpdateItem
    - dynamodb:DeleteItem
    - dynamodb:BatchWriteItem
    - dynamodb:BatchReadItem
  Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:custom.tableName}"
```

And this my lambda yml:

```
functions:
  scraping:
    handler: handler.scraping
    memorySize: 1536
    layers:
      - !Sub 'arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:764866452798:layer:chrome-aws-lambda:22'
    timeout: 15
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: ${self:custom.scheduleRate}
          name: schedule-scraping-${self:provider.stage}
          description: scraping each 5 minute
          enabled: ${self:custom.enabled}
```

In my handle function, I try to insert an item, but I'm getting this error:

```
AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::006977245882:assumed-role/BestSellers-qa-us-east-1-lambdaRole/BestSellers-qa-scraping is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:BatchWriteItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:006977245882:table/TABLE_NAME
   at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
   at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20) ...
```

Comment: have you checked the role permission that you had on your lambda function.?
Its seems to be the permission issue  `BestSellers-qa-scraping is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:BatchWriteItem`.

Comment: When you configure a iamRoleStatements at serverless.yml, at least in theory, all your lambda described functions should inherit that permissions... =\ so no more permissions should be needed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need more specific information about what's wrong. Please describe what you're doing, show your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and clearly explain what's not working about your attempt. We ca't see the DDB table set up here for example and you're not posting your full confirgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've edited/redacted `TABLE_NAME` in the error message, my guess is that you're inadvertently attempting to write to a table which probably doesn't exist (`TABLE_NAME`).

You haven't posted your handler code, but I'd check your code and verify that your actual table name is being set/interpolated correctly before your handler code attempts to insert an item with the DynamoDB API.

Comment: Indeed, there was an error at my custom variables, you're totally right. Thanks a LOT.